# Does a disconnected subset of a metric space need to be equal to the union of its disconnection, or just contained within it?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

If $M$ is a metric space, we say that $M$ is disconnected if there exist two disjoint, open, nonempty sets $A,B$ with $M = A \cup B$.
If $E$ is a subset of $M$, do we necessarily need $E = A \cup B$? Or is $E \subset A \cup B$ sufficient? I believe the latter is sufficient but I'm not sure how to show it.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that if $E$ is a subset of a topological (in particular, metric) space $M$, then a set $U\subseteq E$ is open relative to $E$ if there is an open subset $A$ of $M$ such that $U=E\cap A$.

A subspace $E$ is disconnected if it can be written as a union of open subsets relative to $E$. This means that there are $A,B$ open sets in $M$ such that $U:=E\cap A$ and $V:=E\cap B$ are nonempty disjoint relatively open subsets of $E$ such that $E=U\cup V$. Thus we have $E\subseteq A\cup B$, but we didn't require $A$ and $B$ to be disjoint (only that their intersections with $E$ are disjoint). Thus it is actually neither definition.

Here's an example:

Consider the subspace $E:=\{0,1\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$. It is disconnected, but it cannot be written as a union of disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. However, the sets $A:=(-\infty,1)$ and $B:=(0,\infty)$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$ and give relatively open subsets $U:=E\cap A=\{0\}$ and $V:=E\cap B=\{1\}$ in $E$ such that $E=U\cup V$.